# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, when calling a function

Tags: python, string, function, typeerror, global

I am calling this huge function :

```
arc(w, d, h, name, old_sx_value_1, old_ex_value_1, old_ey_value_1, old_sy_value_4, old_ey_value_4,
    old_ex_value_5, old_sx_value_7, old_sy_value_10, old_sx_value_13, old_ex_value_16, old_sx_value_17,
    old_sx_value_19, old_sy_value_19, old_sy_value_21)
```

The problem is that I receive this error :

```
    ...old_sx_value_19, old_sy_value_19, old_sy_value_21)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I checked and the only str in here is "name", the other ones are floats.
None of the variables above are global, but I have global variables for my paths

Comment: What type is `arc`? Try: `print(type(arc))`. It may be you've defined it to be a `str` string by mistake.

Comment: the type is a string. what does this mean ?

Comment: I just saw my mistake.. i'm answering it now

Comment: Btw, you should definitly try to use **kwargs for the function definition, so you can just pass a dictionnary of values instead of this huge function call.

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`came because I had a global variable with the same name as my function.
I just renamed it and it worked